# jquery touchstart in browser

Tags: jquery, touch-event

As touchstart/touchend is yet not supported in most of the desktop browsers. How can I create touchstart event that will be the same as mousedown event (that is supported in all browsers).

I want something like this

```
$('obj').bind('touchstart', function(e){
});
```

will be translated into

```
$('obj').bind('mousedown', function(e){
})
```

Answer (score 30):

You can bind both at once...

```
$('obj').bind('touchstart mousedown', function(e){
});
```

If you want to `mousedown` event to fire `touchstart` events automatically (so you only need to bind `touchstart`) use...

```
$(document).bind('mousedown', function(event) {
    $(event.target).trigger('touchstart');
});
```

Note that this means `mousedown` events must propagate to `document` before the custom `touchstart` event can be triggered. This could have unexpected side effects.

Comment: These solutions might prove to be a bit problematic if at some point both events will be supported by the same device.

Comment: @epeleg Definitely. In that case, you'd have some code like `"ontouchstart" in document` or similar, and then choose your event name accordingly.

Comment: Perhaps something like `if (Modernizr.touchstart){}` would be appropriate?

Answer (score 9):

Try something like this:

```
var clickEventType = ((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');

$('obj').bind(clickEventType, function(e){});
```

Better yet, use .on() for binding:

```
$('body').on(clickEventType, 'obj', function(e){});
```

This checks document to see if touchstart exists, if it does, then your event is 'touchstart' if it doesn't (most desktop browsers) then its 'click'.

You can also trigger using the same event type:

```
$('obj').trigger(clickEventType);
```

Comment: I also Gist-ified it so you can just copy and paste the whole thing: https://gist.github.com/esteinborn/9398782

Answer (score 1):

It's not the nicest solution, but the best I found till now. Downfall? It only works after first touch happened so you cannot use synchronously :(

```
 var isTouch = false;
 $('body').on('touchstart', function () {
    isTouch = true;
 });
```

You can also check if browser support touch first with modernizr for example.

Remember to don't use it in global scope (unless you have to). You can also change it to be modernizr "alike" by adding is-touch-device class to Html tag by adding after `isTouch = true` code: `$('html').addClass('is-touch-device')`. In this case you can reference it from everywhere (from css also).