# Is there an add-on or extension to emulate touch events?

Tags: javascript, mobile, touch, dom-events

In order to develop and debug mobile and tablet applications, I'd like to be able to have my mouse emulate `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchen`d.

I have found two possibilities:

Phantom Limb
http://www.vodori.com/blog/phantom-limb.html
(doesn't seem to work)

ChromeTouch
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ncegfehgjifmmpnjaihnjpbpddjjebme
(Scrolls the page, but doesn't fire touch events)

Does anyone know of an addon that will fire touch events in a desktop webkit browser?

Comment: This is a good alternative, but doesn't work as well for emulating 'touchmove' during development: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389968/jquery-touchstart-in-browser

Comment: Answered over here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10150177/89484 You can enable touch event emulation in Chrome DevTools now.

Comment: Select **Emulate touch events** in the Dev Tools Settings panel. (To get at Settings, click the gear/cog icon at the bottom right of the tools.)

You can then emulate touch events with your mouse, and set break points (in the Scripts panel) for touch event listener functions

Comment: Not only is there no "gear" icon in Chrome anymore, but setting "enable touch emulation" does absolutely nothing for me, dev tools open or closed.  What happened!?  Why has this feature been removed!?  So frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I found to execute touchmove was to do something manually coded like this:

```
(function(){

var isDown = false
,   dragging
;

$('body').bind('mousedown', function(){ isDown = true; });
$('body').bind('mousemove', function(){ if(isDown) { dragging(); } });    
$('body').bind('touchmove', function(){ dragging(); });
$('body').bind('mouseup', function(){ isDown = false; });

dragging = function () {
    console.log('content being drug');
}

})();
```