# jQuery mobile (click event)

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, button, click

I'm developing smartphone hybrid applications.

I'm trying to hide/show a `<div>` with `slideDown`/`slideUp`.

When I click on the button, the menu `<div>` is supposed to hide/show depend of the context. Everything is working well on my computer but it just doesn't work at all on my mobile, nothing happens.

Here is my HTML code

```
<a class="btnMenuDyn" data-role="button">Masquer le menu</a>
```

and here my jQuery mobile code:

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(e){


// définition des variables
var btnMenuDyn = $('a.btnMenuDyn'),
    menuDyn = $('div.menuDyn');

$(btnMenuDyn).bind('click', function(){


    // condition pour afficher ou non le menu
    if ($(menuDyn).hasClass("menuDynHide"))
    {
        $(menuDyn).slideDown().removeClass("menuDynHide");
    }
    else{
        $(menuDyn).slideUp().addClass("menuDynHide");
    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this problem is mobiles do not support click they use touchstart and touchend so can track movement if you still want to test on computers you can do this

```
$(btnMenuDyn).bind('touchstart mousedown', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(menuDyn).hasClass("menuDynHide"))
    {
        $(menuDyn).slideDown().removeClass("menuDynHide");
    }
    else{
        $(menuDyn).slideUp().addClass("menuDynHide");
    }

});
```

another question with same answer [jquery touchstart in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389968/jquery-touchstart-in-browser)

more infomation can be found at http://backtothecode.blogspot.com/2009/10/javascript-touch-and-gesture-events.html

Comment: Yes it was touchstart to add, and e.preventdefault to get the perfect result.

Thanks.

Comment: Be careful using touchstart. That can be triggered unintentionally when the user is trying to swipe to scroll. I'd recommend at least using touchend. Ideally you'd update the UI on touchstart and only act on touchend. I created a plugin which will do this [jquery-touchclick](https://github.com/tuxracer/jquery-touchclick)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `on()` instead of `bind()`

And since youre doing this:

```
var btnMenuDyn = $('a.btnMenuDyn')
```

`btnMenuDyn` is a jquery dom element, so change this:

```
if ($(menuDyn).hasClass("menuDynHide"))
```

to this

```
if (menuDyn.hasClass("menuDynHide"))
```

And preferably declare jquery dom elements like this:

```
var $btnMenuDyn = $('a.btnMenuDyn')
```

Comment: I would disagree with declaring jquery dom elements with the $ prefix, namely because of php's legacy usage of the $, whereas jquery just showed up recently.

Comment: +1 for using on instead of bind (see here why http://api.jquery.com/bind/)
-1 for naming a variable with the $ prefix
So the result is neutral :)

Comment: @victorvartan http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205853/why-would-a-javascript-variable-start-with-a-dollar-sign But of course it comes down to personal preferences. If you don't like it, don't use it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right, it is a matter of style. Perhaps because I'm working more with type-safe languages I see no good reason to use the hungarian notation. I guess the second half of my comment was too objective, so that leaves the +1 :)

Comment: @victorvartan It's actually the only time when I find it necessary to indicate the data type in Javascript. When it comes to comparing variables, I stick to `===` in JS, because it's eqvivalent to `==` in strongly typed languages.