# jquery click event not firing on mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, click, touch

I have the following script. Works on desktops but not on my mobile? Is there an alternative to '.click' to work on mobile and desktops or should I look into jQuery mobile?

```
$("#showMenu").click(function() {
    $('#logo, #details-wrapper, #side-text').fadeIn();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplication here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11332533/jquery-mobile-click-event   and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10722730/jquery-click-event-not-working-in-mobile-browsers

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery Mobile's `tap` event instead: [DOC: TAP EVENT](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/)

> The jQuery Mobile tap event triggers after a quick, complete touch event that occurs on a single target object. It is the gesture equivalent of a standard click event that is triggered on the release state of the touch gesture.

For more information about jQuery Mobile's events, check the online doc: [DOC: JQM EVENTS](http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/methods/)