# how to check checkbox on div click in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently have this layout:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <input class="checkboxOption" type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">Clinical Pharmacology (sub req'd)</div>
        </div><!--input-group-->

        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <input class="checkboxOption" type="checkbox">
            </div>
            <div class="form-control">Clinicaltrials.gov</div>
        </div><!--input-group-->
    </div>
</div>
```

and I want to be able to just click the input-group or the form-control and check the checkbox nested inside.

I currently have this in my popup.js:

```
$(".form-control").on("touchstart", checkInside);

function checkInside(e) {
    var box = $(".input-group > .input-group-addon > .checkboxOption");
    if(box.checked){
        box.attr('checked', false);
     } else{
         box.attr('checked', true);
     }
 }
```

but when I place console.log statements in the function, it seems as if the click isn't even registering. is there another approach to this, or something else?

Comment: Are you using mobile?

Comment: Touchstart? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389968/jquery-touchstart-in-browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a Jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mc120Lem/)

use :

```
prop('checked', false);
```

instead of :

```
box.attr('checked', false);
```

touchstart will work only on mobile (or debug mode).

Comment: thank you so much. this is the answer i am looking for. there are a LOT of checkboxes, changing the html  would not be fun

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be achieved with `<label>` elements tied to the `id`s of the checkboxes. Basically wrap a `<label>` around everything you want to be able to click to check a checkbox, and add `for="checkboxID"` where checckboxID is the id of the checkbox.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0n5Lsf3L/).

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need jQuery or Javascript to make it work.

Example:

```
<input id="checkboxID" type="checkbox" />
<label for="checkboxID">This will check/uncheck the checkbox with the ID 'checkboxID' if clicked</label>
```

or

```
<input id="checkboxID2" type="checkbox" />
<div>
   <label for="checkboxID2">This will check/uncheck the checkbox with the ID 'checkboxID2' if clicked</label>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4mqm4acz/)