# Issue with trigger click on touch devices when targeting data element

Tags: javascript, jquery, touchstart

I am attempting to trigger a click via jQuery while targeting a data elements. The trigger click works perfectly fine on desktop devices, however on touch devices it's failing. I was doing some reading here: [jquery touchstart in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9389968/jquery-touchstart-in-browser) and attempted to bind a touchstart event, but it's still not working, below is my code with and without the touchstart event.

```
//basic implementation that works on non-touch devices
$('.mobile-link').click(function() {
      $("[data-slidr-breadcrumbs='platforms']").trigger('click');
});

//with touchstart
var clickEventType = ((document.ontouchstart!==null)?'click':'touchstart');

$('.mobile-link').click(function() {
    $([data-slidr-breadcrumbs='platforms']).trigger(clickEventType);
});
```

Comment: is that the attribute selector you are calling is correct??

Comment: The attribute selector seems to be correct since it's working on non-touch devices. Though, I wonder if the problem within touch devices stems from that somehow?

Answer (score -1):

You want either click or touchstart events so use [.on()](https://api.jquery.com/on) and pass the event name as the first param

```
var clickEventType = ((document.ontouchstart !== null) ? 'click' : 'touchstart');

$('.mobile-link').on(clickEventType, function () {
    $("[data-slidr-breadcrumbs='platforms']").trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that's still not doing the trick, the click function fires properly - for example if I add an alert it fires upon click, the issue though, still exists from the trigger click not firing on the data attribute element.